# How to identify an EventCallback using reflection

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection, blazor, blazor-webassembly

#### Setup

I have an `interface` which has a handful of `EventCallbacks`, some of which are generic.

I am using `System.Reflection.GetProperties()` to look at all the properties in the `interface`

Right now I use something like `ProcessEventCallbacks` below, to ascertain weather a property is an [EventCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallback?view=aspnetcore-8.0), [EventCallback<TItem>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallback-1?view=aspnetcore-8.0), or not, and what I don't like is that I am doing a string comparison   to get the answer.

#### Question

> Is there a way to determine if `propInfo.PropertyType` is either an [EventCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallback?view=aspnetcore-8.0) or [EventCallback<TItem>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallback-1?view=aspnetcore-8.0) without using string comparison?

#### What I've tried

- I put a watch on `propInfo` and browsed the object looking for the answer
- Studied [EventCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallback?view=aspnetcore-8.0) and [EventCallback<TItem>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallback-1?view=aspnetcore-8.0) in Microsoft's documentation
- Internet searches
- Type Comparason

  - `propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(EventCallback)`
  - `propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(EventCallback<TItem>)`
    The problem there are many generic types and many generic **EventCallbacks** an I would prefer not to write a case for each generic type.

```cs
public interface ICustomList<TItem> where TItem : class
{
    public TItem Item { get; set; }
    public EventCallback OnListUpdated { get; set; }
    public EventCallback<TItem> OnItemAdded { get; set; }
} 

public class CustomList<TItem> : ICustomList<TItem> 
    where TItem : class
{
    protected void ProcessEventCallbacks()
    {
        Type iType = typeof(ICustomList<TItem>);
        PropertyInfo[] iPropertyInfo = iType.GetProperties();

        Array.ForEach(iPropertyInfo, propInfo =>
        {
            string propName = propInfo.PropertyType.Name;
            
            if (propName.Contains('EventCallback')
            {
                // Do some processing...

                /******************************************************
                    These are the possible values in this situation
                        propName == 'EventCallback`1'
                        propName == 'EventCallback'
                ******************************************************/
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Solution

Credit to [@madreflection](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394572/madreflection)

```cs
protected void ProcessEventCallbacks()
{
    Type iType = typeof(ICustomList<TItem>);

    PropertyInfo[] iProps = iType.GetProperties();

    iProps.Where(prop =>
        prop.PropertyType == typeof(EventCallback)
        ||
        (
            prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType
            &&
            prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
                typeof(EventCallback<>)
        )
    ).ToList().ForEach(propInfo =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Answer: {propInfo.Name} is {propInfo.PropertyType.Name}");
    });
}
```

This prints out:

```
Answer: OnDone is EventCallback
Answer: ItemChanged is EventCallback`1
Answer: EditingChanged is EventCallback`1
Answer: CanSaveChanged is EventCallback`1
Answer: OnConfirmSave is EventCallback`1
Answer: OnConfirmRemove is EventCallback`1
Answer: OnCreate is EventCallback`1
Answer: OnUpdate is EventCallback`1
Answer: OnRemove is EventCallback`1
Answer: OnSave is EventCallback`1
Answer: OnCancel is EventCallback`1
Answer: OnBeginEditing is EventCallback`1
```

Comment: Is generic type... Take a look at Type class documentation...

Comment: Also you can  compare types and use typeof... `propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(EventCallback)`... `propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(EventCallback<TItem>)`

Comment: Off-topic comment: don't use ToList().ForEach... Just iterate array or use static Array.ForEach

Comment: @Selvin, I forgot to mention that I used the approach `propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(EventCallback) ...`, the problem is there are many `EventCallbacks` with many different types, so I would have to compare all different types... Thank you, this comment helped me understand my question a little better.

Comment: `propInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EventCallback<>)`

Comment: @Selvin Personally I would suggest to stay away from all forms of `ForEach` and just use a normal `foreach(...)` loop

Comment: @madreflection, That got me to a solution. Thanks. I'm going to add the solution to my question but you should get the credit for the answer.

Comment: @madreflection, I'll mark that as the answer if you feel like posting it as an **Answer**

Comment: @Selvin, how do I fix that ForEach :)